# If I were to set up a router to route network traffic directly through a VPN, do I lose the advantages of PFS?

Tags: security, vpn, internet-security

I have been learning about the advantages of connecting to the internet via a VPN but before I jump in with both feet I’ve decided to do some reading around the subject to understand what I’m getting in to.

VPN providers use perfect forward secrecy (PFS) in order to help encrypt connections. This involves generating a session key for each session initiated by a user. It is also an option to configure a router to direct all traffic via the VPN at source. My question is:

By configuring a router to connect directly to the VPN provider, is the session kept permanently open thus negating the effects of PFS?

Answer (score 1):

I have made numerous site to site and client to site IPsec VPN tunnels and always kept PFS OFF.

The resulting tunnels remain secure (both types) and, in particular, site to site tunnels remain up all the time. This is a distinct advantage.

I reviewed this setting with a Consultant specializing in VPN and his recommendation was to leave it unchecked (OFF)

I trust this helps you.